# How Can I Set RSAParameters (of RSACryptoServiceProvider) to an RSA Public Key Directly

Tags: c#, jwt, rsa

To create the necessary validation parameters in order to call JwtSecurityTokenHandler ValidateToken()...

I know I can do this:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportParameters(new RSAParameters() 
    {                
        Modulus = "",
        Exponent = ""
    });

var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa)
    };
```

I would like to set the public key directly instead of setting the Modulus and Exponent individually. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean "from a file's contents"? or just "with fewer lines of code"?

Comment: I mean "with fewer lines of code". I will have the public key in the form of a string (temporarily hard coded to get things working locally). I just don't want to have to break the key into Modulus and Exponent to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your saved key looks like the xmldsig RSAKeyValue (`<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>base64</Modulus><Exponent>base64</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>`), and you're not on .NET Core, you can use `rsa.FromXmlString(keyString)`.

If your saved key format is changed to the `byte[]` representation of a CAPI blob then you can use `rsa.ImportCspBlob(keyBlob)`.

If your saved key format is changed to the `byte[]` representation of a CNG blob then you can use `new RSACng(CngKey.Import(blob, blobType))`

Otherwise, you have the minimum code you can have, with the following nuggets of thought:

- You could make a function to build the RSAParameters from your storage format.
- Change your local storage format to be the two arrays.
- Change your hard coded format to just be an RSAParameters object intializer, you can import from it more than once...

Comment: I am not on .NET Core. It looks like rsa.FromXmlString(keyString) is exactly what I have been looking for. Also, I will seriously consider the nuggets of thought you mentioned. I really appreciate your response. This saves me a lot of time and sheds a lot of light.